# Do mirror images benefit from the increased damage of Slow Time: Time Warp?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

Do mirror images from the Diablo 3 Wizard Spell "Mirror Images" or "Teleport: Fracture" benefit from the increased damage of the Time Warp rune for Slow Time?

*theoretical build example:* 
http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/wizard#QlgkSd!RWeS!YZbZYb

**Slow Time: Time Warp** - Enemies caught in the bubble of warped time take 15% more damage.

Comment: Slow time bubbles (and many other spells) are colored different per rune. If the bubbles they create are the same color as yours, I would assume that it does include the secondary effects.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a closer look next time I cast the spell. I never really noticed the color difference when playing... to much going on around me.

Comment: This question is unclear to me. Are you asking if the images cast a slow time that debuffs, or if the MI benefit from the debuff?

Comment: Ok I just saw the edit and I think the actual question was clearer in the first revision

Answer (score 1):

Yep, they benefit. Any skill that involves the words '[targets] take more damage' means that the target takes additional damage from *any* source, whether it be you, your pets, another player or an NPC. The only exception is when that phrase is qualified with something like, 'take more damage *from* you/your [skill]/your pets'.

It's skills that are worded 'you do more damage' or 'your [skill] does more damage' that the to be more selective about the damage source.

Answer (score 0):

Decoys add a percentage of damage to your general attack per instance, but do not infer secondary effects such as slow, or damage reduction.

Comment: The OP is asking whether Mirror Images' damage is amplified by Time Warp, not is the apply slows or damage reduction. And the bit about "adding a percentage of damage to your attack", is plain wrong. They don't, they make their own attacks.

Comment: Given there is a comment regarding how to test if the decoys are casting the bubble with the same secondary effect, and the OP found it useful to the question, I think it is just as safe to assume OP wishes to stack damage increases.

Comment: My bad, I got this backwards, not amplifying Mirror Images's damage but using them to amplify yours. Still, what do you mean by decoys "adding a percentage to your attacks"?

Comment: I mean that your general damage as a result of the attack increases. They cast the ability independently, but are deliberately reacting to the player casting the spell. Also, they do not cast at full power, only a small percent of the players actual power (10% or something like that?)

I can not remember off the top of my head if they target identical to the player, mind. I've seen it play out on a friend's character through coop.

Comment: And that's what I am pointing out. In a game where numbers matter so much, there is a difference between "another attack for 10% damage" and "+10% damage to your attack".